# Count in each distinct row in sequential order

Tags: sql

I'm running a SQL query that displays the value below.

Currently the results are appear as such:

```
 AccountNum         FieldName           FieldValue      DisplayOrder
1000    |   SalesYTD    |   0   |   1
1000    |   SalesTTM    |   0   |   1
1000    |   ReturnsYTD  |   0   |   1
1000    |   ReturnsTTM  |   0   |   1
2000    |   SalesYTD    |   0   |   1
2000    |   SalesTTM    |   0   |   1
2000    |   ReturnsYTD  |   0   |   1
2000    |   ReturnsTTM  |   0   |   1
```

I would like it to appear like this:

```
AccountNum         FieldName           FieldValue      DisplayOrder
1000    |   SalesYTD    |   0   |   1
1000    |   SalesTTM    |   0   |   2
1000    |   ReturnsYTD  |   0   |   3
1000    |   ReturnsTTM  |   0   |   4
2000    |   SalesYTD    |   0   |   1
2000    |   SalesTTM    |   0   |   2
2000    |   ReturnsYTD  |   0   |   3
2000    |   ReturnsTTM  |   0   |   4
```

What am I doing wrong? Sample code below.  Thanks.

```
Select distinct(accountnum)as AccountID, 
      '|' as bar1,
     'SalesYTD' as FieldName,
      '|' as bar2,
      Isnull(SUB100.YTDGrossSalesTY, 0) as FieldValue,
      '|' as bar3,
      row_number() over(partition by accountnum order by [accountnum]) as DisplayOrder,
      '|' as bar4,
      a.salesgroup as 'RepID'
from Custtable as A
```

Comment: You cant use distinct to one column on select list, and you dont' have to do it. Ordering by accountnum is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `PARTITION`'s `ORDER BY`, I prefer to use `RANK`.  Also in SQL SERVER DISTINCT is not a single column operation.

```
    Select accountnum as AccountID, 
      '|' as bar1,
     'SalesYTD' as FieldName,
      '|' as bar2,
      Isnull(SUB100.YTDGrossSalesTY, 0) as FieldValue,
      '|' as bar3,
      RANK() over(partition by accountnum order by [Fieldname]) as DisplayOrder,
      '|' as bar4,
      a.salesgroup as 'RepID'
    from Custtable as A 

    Left Join [dbo].[DIRPARTYNAMEPRIMARYADDRESSVIEW] DPA with(Nolock)
    on a.party = dpa.party
    and a.PARTITION = DPA.PARTITION
    and [VALIDTO] > Getdate() 

    Left Join 
    (
    Select 
           cij.ORDERACCOUNT,

       SUM(Case when cij.dataareaid = 'CHE' Then 
                (Case When @currency in (2, 3) Then (cij.salesbalance)
                     Else (cij.salesbalancemst)
                 End)                  
                When cij.dataareaid = 'CHS' Then 
                     (Case When @currency = 1 Then (cij.salesbalancemst * (Case When cij.CURRENCYCODE = 'USD' Then 100 Else Isnull(ex.exchrate,1) End)/100)
                          Else (cij.salesbalancemst)
                      End)
                When cij.dataareaid = 'CHJ' Then 
                     (Case When @currency = 1 Then (cij.salesbalancemst * (Case When cij.CURRENCYCODE = 'USD' Then 100 Else Isnull(ex.exchrate,1) End)/100)
                          Else (cij.salesbalancemst)
                      End) 
           End) as YTDGrossSalesTY

from dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR cij With(Nolock)

LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].V_Exchrates EX WITH(NOLOCK)
                          ON ex.[Name] = 'CHE'                          
                          and DatePart(mm, Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = DatePart(mm, ex.fromdate)
                          and DatePart(yy, Dateadd(mm, -1, Getdate())) = DatePart(yy, ex.fromdate)
                          and DatePart(dd, ex.fromdate) = 1
                                           and ex.Tocurrencycode = 'USD'
                          and ex.fromcurrencycode = cij.CURRENCYCODE

where (cij.dataareaid in ('CHE', 'CHS')
and cij.ORDERACCOUNT not in ('CHS', 'CHJ')  -- Exclude CHS sales
and cij.invoicedate > '2011-05-31' 
and Left(cij.invoiceid,2) != 'CM' 
and Left(cij.invoiceid,2) != 'FT' 
and Datepart(yy, cij.INVOICEDATE) = datepart(yy, Getdate())
and cij.INVOICEDATE <= Getdate())
or
(cij.dataareaid = 'CHJ'
and cij.invoicedate > '2011-05-31' 
and Left(cij.invoiceid,2) != 'CM' 
and Left(cij.invoiceid,2) != 'FT' 
and Datepart(yy, cij.INVOICEDATE) = datepart(yy, Getdate())
and cij.INVOICEDATE <= Getdate()
and Left(cij.ORDERACCOUNT, 2) = 'JP') 

Group by cij.ORDERACCOUNT
)
SUB100 
on SUB100.ORDERACCOUNT = accountnum
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  When I try this, the fieldname is not found.  Could it be because the SalesYTD and is not an actual data on the DB, but just some sort of a filler data for that fieldname column?

Comment: now that i look at the query: `Isnull(SUB100.YTDGrossSalesTY, 0) a`, is not valid as there is no `SUB100` table referenced in the query.

Comment: I've added the more code, to represent the calculation for the sub100 table.  This repeats 3 other times to represent the FieldName.  Hope I'm stating this right.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: well, FieldName is a computed column, it can't be used anywhere other than in the ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with.

```
Select distinct(accountnum)as AccountID, 
      '|' as bar1,
     'SalesYTD' as FieldName,
      '|' as bar2,
      Isnull(SUB100.YTDGrossSalesTY, 0) as FieldValue,
      '|' as bar3,
      Fieldname = '1',
      '|' as bar4,
      a.salesgroup as 'RepID'
from Custtable as A
```